# Displaying button group vertically

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-button, styleclass

I'm using lightning-button-group in my LWC component however, by default it displays the grouped buttons horizontally - in one row. How would I change it to display vertically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SLDS in itself does not support vertical button groups -> LWC's don't either.

So you will have to create the component yourself, just beware that there is good reason why you can't create vertical buttons - either you get staggered edges of the buttons or you get too wide buttons resulting in rather weird looking layout.

I would think over the layout from UX perspective - maybe you don't need them at all.

Btw: when writing the CSS you can reuse the Dropdown Items from Overflow Menu:
[SLDS Button Group - Overflow Menu](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/button-groups/#With-Overflow-Menu-Open)  - this might be visually OK for some use cases.